# matplotlib does not show any plot window with xarray's plot() on Python 3.6.5

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-xarray

I was trying to plot with matplotlib and xarray on Python 3.6.5.

My code is actually from the [xarray documentation](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/plotting.html):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import xarray as xr

airtemps = xr.tutorial.open_dataset('air_temperature')
print(airtemps)

air = airtemps.air - 273.15
air.attrs = airtemps.air.attrs
air.attrs['units'] = 'deg C'
air1d = air.isel(lat=10, lon=10)
air1d.plot()      # using xarray.DataArray's plot()
```

When I ran the code (within the virturlenv) it didn't show any plotting window and no error was thrown.

Comment: Supposedly you forgot to call `plt.show()` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

My mistake I forgot to call plt.show() at the end.